# Visualforce Home page component on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom Visualforce Tab and a visualforce home page component that is not showing custom links because the size of the home page component is not rendering at what we have specified. Is there a way to make sure the home page component is the same height on all tabs?

[image]

Comment: Is this a Custom Home Page Component?

Comment: Yes it is a custom home page component.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Custom Home Page components don't have a "fluid" height. You can only specify it's height in pixels.

You can view this by going to...

```
Customise > Home > Home Page Components
```

... And clicking `Edit` next to your component.

[image]

You've really got two options:

1. Tick `Show Scrollbars` which I believe will show links that are hiddent
2. Use Standard Custom Links which can be found at the top under **Standard Components**. You can simply add in the "text to display" and the URL the link should take the user to.

[image]